# How to find hourly wage when data only provide range?

Tags: econometrics, labor-economics, applied-econometrics, r

I am trying to separate observations into two groups, people who earn below (treatment group) and above (control group) the minimum wage to perform a difference-in-differences.

The data I'm using have information on monthly income and weekly hours worked. But the issue is monthly income is given in range, whereas weekly hours worked are given in actual values. My solution to this is to convert hours worked from weekly to monthly then categorise them in range. I would then divide the lower and upper bounds of monthly income by the bounds of hours worked to find out hourly wage. Since these would still be a range of values, which means at some point people at the lower bound would be earning below the minimum wage but people at the upper bound would be earning above.

My aim is to find out the hourly wage and compare it with the minimum wage, thereby allowing me to separate observations into treatment and control groups.

My explanation may lack clarity so below is my dataframe

```
    dput(data.compressed)
structure(list(totpinc = structure(c(2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 
5, 4), labels = c(`ineligible - not currently employed/ self employed` = -2, 
`ineligible - under 16yrs` = -1, `             less than £  215` = 1, 
`£  215 to less than £  435` = 2, `£  435 to less than £  870` = 3, 
`£  870 to less than £1305` = 4, `£1305 to less than £1740` = 5, 
`£1740 to less than £2820` = 6, `£2820 to less than £3420` = 7, 
`£3420 to less than £3830` = 8, `£3830 to less than £4580` = 9, 
`£4580 to less than £6670` = 10, `£6670 or more` = 11, `eligible (current employee or self-emp) - dk/ refuse income` = 12
), label = "total net monthly personal income (for employees & self-employed together)", class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double")), hrs_grp = c(3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 
2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```